# Is it possible to store a boolean in a String in Java

Tags: java, string, boolean

I am trying to store the boolean of `m.find()` which comes out to be true. I want my program to print `"Successful"` when it is true. How can i check if the boolean is true with an `if` statement? How would I do this since I can't store a boolean in the string answer like i have in my sample code?

Here is what i have so far.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("22:30");
    System.out.println(m.find());
    String answer = m.find();

    if(answer==true){
        System.out.println("Successful");
    }
```

UPDATE

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("22:30");
    System.out.println(m.find());

    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Successful");
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to assign the result of `m.find` (which is `boolean`) to a `String`, and then interpreting as a `boolean`?  Just `if (m.find()) { ... }`.

Comment: In `boolean_value == true`, the comparison is completely superfluous. Leave it out.

Comment: `How can i check if the boolean is true with an if statement?` - errr, I hate to be rude, but perhaps you need to brush up on the basics...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That's what I did first. But it isn't working. The program just stops.

Comment: @John3136 I'm that guy that's in the wrong college course ;)

Comment: Then you did something else wrong. Please update your question with that code, so we can help you with it.

Comment: @Tom updated it now.

Comment: Too bad that I'm on a phone and I don't have an IDE available, but it looks like that your second version of your test subject "222:d30" contains an additional "2" (which doesn't match the pattern) and the "d" isn't allowed either. Try "22:30" like in your first example, that should work.

Comment: @Tom Yes that was a miss paste. The boolean is still true and still doesn't run the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it is better to store a `boolean` as a `boolean`.

```
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Successful");
}
```

or

```
String answer = Boolean.toString(m.find());
if(answer.equals("true")){
    System.out.println("Successful");
}
```

or

```
String answer = m.find() ? "Successful" : "Unsuccessful";
System.out.println(answer);
```

**But** your pattern will only match once, so you can only call `find()` once.

Comment: Make sure you aren't calling `find()` twice (as you are above). Your input only matches your pattern *once*.